# cut curve out of circle

Tags: python

I am trying to cut out a pattern which I made as a curve from a circle using python. 
I made the pattern using this and adding all the curves together to form 1 curve.

```
 if i==0:
    coords = measure.approximate_polygon(contour, tolerance=1.2)
    x0,y0= coords[0]
else:
    coords = measure.approximate_polygon(contour, tolerance=1.2)

print(coords)
# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '2D'
curveData.resolution_u = 0

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(coords)-1)
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):


    x,y = (coord+[0])
    polyline.points[i].co = (x-x0, y-y0, 0, 0)
    if x-x0<minX:
        minX=x-x0
    if x-x0>maxX:
        maxX=x-x0
    if y-y0<minY:
        minY=y-y0
    if y-y0>maxY:
        maxY=y-y0
# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)
curveData.bevel_depth = 0

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
```

To make a circle and cut out the curve I made:

```
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:


 if ob.type == 'CURVE':
        ob.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
    else:
        ob.select = False
bpy.ops.object.join()
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'CURVE':
        ob.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    print(ob)
pattern = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("myCurve")



def csgSubtract(target, opObj):
    '''subtract opObj from the target'''

    # Deselect All
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # Select the new object.
    target.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = target

    # Add a modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')

    mod = target.modifiers
    mod[0].name = "SubEmUp"
    mod[0].object = opObj
    mod[0].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'

    # Apply modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=mod[0].name)

def makePrimitiveCircle(objName, v, r, f, loc, rot, layers=[0]):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
        vertices=v, 
        radius=r, 
        fill_type=f, 
        view_align=False, 
        enter_editmode=False, 
        location=loc, 
        rotation=rot,
        layers=[(i in layers) for i in range(20)])
    ob = bpy.context.active_object
    ob.name = objName
    ob.show_name = True
    me = ob.data
    me.name = objName + 'Mesh'
    return ob
rad=(maxX-minX)/2
print(minX,minY,maxX,maxY)
f = makePrimitiveCircle('Circle', 200, rad, 'NGON', ((maxX-rad),(maxY-rad),0), (0,0,0))
```

it gives an error at `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA',modifier=mod[0].name)` but I have no idea how to fix it, this is my first blender project and I am kinda stuck..

error is:

```
   bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=mod[0].name)
   File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
  RuntimeError: Error: Modifier is disabled, skipping apply
```

Comment: Welcome to bse. Can you provide how you are calling the method that calls the modifier apply operator that is throwing the error?  It does look like the same error you would get when the modifier is red in the UI and you press apply prob. because the `object` property is not set correctly.

Comment: oh sorry! I stopped one line to soon with my copy. `csgSubtract(f,pattern)`

Comment: Don't think you can use a mix of curve and mesh objects in boolean operations. Try   convert curve to mesh first.

Comment: I tried that, however I got the following error when trying to convert: `attributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'convert'`